# What's causing my random magnet effect?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

Sometimes, I get random magnetic effects like you typically see with Magneto. What could be causing me to have these magnetic properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been reported as a side effect of the new 3 Dollar bill item(as you can see [here](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items#Wrath_of_the_Lamb_Collectible_Items) on the wiki).

It's probably a bug, since that item is intended to affect your shot's behaviour, not the items surrounding you.

Comment: Well, this is a bug that I am definitely okay with :p

Comment: @spugsley totally agreed :)